# If $x-(1/10+1/20+1/30+1/40+1/50+1/60+1/70+1/80+1/90) = 12.08$ what is the value of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$x-(1/10+1/20+1/30+1/40+1/50+1/60+1/70+1/80+1/90) = 12.08 $$
 what is the value of $x$?

Comment: What do you find difficult here?  Granted, adding fractions is a bit tedious, but it's not exactly difficult.  Maybe it helps to multiply by $10$.  Then you just need to add $\frac 11+\frac 12+\cdots+ \frac 19$.

Comment: How would you usually solve an equation "$x$ minus something equals something else"?

Answer (score 2):

$$x=(1/10+1/20+1/30+1/40+1/50+1/60+1/70+1/80+1/90) + 12.08 $$

Comment: $62309/5040$, courtesy of Pari-GP

Comment: @egreg: provided the numerical value $12.08$ is exact. :)